# scanf and point to int* segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, scanf

I call my program and it is to read a bunch fo integers from the standard input

```
int main() {
    int* s;
    derp(s);
    return 0;
}

void derp(int *size) {
    scanf("%d", size);
}
```

why is this code causing a segmentation fault?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int* s;
derp(s);
```

What does `s` point to? To random garbage memory since its not initialized. You should do this instead:

```
int s;
derp(&s);
```

or you could allocate storage space using `malloc`:

```
int* s = malloc( sizeof(int) );
derp(s);
free(s);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you need to initialize s.

Add this:

```
s = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Remember to `free(s)` when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

s needs to be initialized using malloc().  As it is now, s points to some random crap somewhere in memory.